# Passing strings and vectors by value in c++

Tags: c++, vector, reference, copy-constructor, stdstring

first I know this is a terrible thing to do as it may require large amounts of memory copying... but it needs to be done because of specifications I have been given.

Anyway, I am trying to pass a string by reference and a vector by value as it will be edited then destroyed and then the original will be used again.

Here is the function prototype

```
int print (const string& findme,const string& command,const string& command2,const string& command3, int n, vector<string> list)
```

and here is my call, all variables are of the correct type.

```
print (special,command,command2,command3,n,temp);
```

Everything compiles and runs when I do not attempt to call the function... but when I do I get this error:

```
a2p1.cc: In function âint main(int, char**)â:
a2p1.cc:85: error: no match for call to â(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >) (std::string&, std::string&, std::string&, std::string&, int&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&)â
```

SO I was wondering... how should I be passing these strings and the vector to the function the strings can be passed by reference but I need a copy of the vector, any syntax help would be very helpful! Thanks!

Here are the variables

```
    int n;

    string command = "rr";
    string command3 = "null";
    string command2 = "f";
    string japan;
    string special;
    special = "fnord";
    string textFileName;

    vector<string> list;
    vector<string> print;
```

And here is the call to the function, on line 83:

```
while (cin >> inputtemp)
{
...

if ((inputtemp == "p")){

print (special,command,command2,command3,n,list);

}// If
}// While
```

Comment: What's.. the function definition?

Comment: You've just tasted a bit of template-debugging goodness.

Comment: I'm sorry but the function definition is rather large and I'm not actually able to post it due to IP concerns.

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to return a vector from print()? That's what the error seems to imply.

Comment: What is on line 85 of a2p1.cc anyway?

Comment: The function only has two return statements both constant, 1 for failure and 0 for successful.

Comment: Line 85 contains the call to the function. sorry, should have made that clear.

Comment: Can you show that line, as well as the declarations of the variables used in the call? (I know, you said they are of the right types, but perhaps there is something you overlooked.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow... I'll just add them there.

Comment: The error message seems to suggest that instead of `print(...)` you actually call `temp(...)` by accident. You are sure that is not the case?

Comment: Within your error message, it seems to be looking for a reference to int (`int&`) while the function declaration is `int` - I'd look there for a start.

Comment: You have declared a vector named `print` (same as your function). Don't do that. Choose a different name for the variable.

Comment: No hard feelings, but I am going to vote to close as "too localised". It's a simple name clash. Can happen.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help... I'm sorry I missed something like that. Thanks for your time and please forgive my failures.

Comment: @Yuushi: All that means is that he passed a modifiable l-value int to the function.  That's perfectly compatible with the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both a function and a variable named `print`.

You're not actually calling the `print` function.

Rename the variable.

*(Your function prototype is correct.  It will do what you describe)*

Look again at your error to see this.  (I removed the templates to make it simpler)

```
error: no match for call to (std::vector) (std::string&, std::string&, std::string&, std::string&, int&, std::vector&)
```